# Php resume execution at same state after crash/shutdown of server

Tags: php

I'm curious to find out a right way to my requirement

Suppose your php code is ->

```
<?php 
for ($i=1; $i <= 100 ; $i++) { 
    sleep(1); #sleep for a second 
    echo "\n $i*2=". $i * 2 ; #do some work
}
?>
```

The above program prints table of 2 **every second** and will execute **until 100 seconds**.

Suppose on **50th second** the server is **crashed/reboot/shutdown**.

Now is that possible to **resume back on 51st second** with the same state of PHP including temp/local values and variables.

Alternatively is that possible to hibernate the execution of PHP. If PHP is not the answer, is their any other language that I can use.

Comment: This is a guess. I tried the code above and the server does not time out if your only loop 5 times instead of 100 times. maybe, for some reason, the loop does not wait for the sleep() but sleep() only prevents the output. It probably racks up 100 seconds of sleep and times out.

Comment: @Kobbe my code is for reference purpose only :-)

Comment: A given PHP script execution time is usually a few milliseconds. Keeping the server busy for minutes on end would soon bring the server to its knees if a few dozen clients showed up at the same time. Not to mention that the clients would most likely time out, unless the script were feeding them whatever content every few seconds. But having the system automatically backup the state of each running script is simply impossible. It's like asking a word processor to backup your files every second, or your computer to restart in the state he was in one second before a power failure.

Comment: @kuroineko let's say, I'm using cron jobs, single thread, is that possible now?

Comment: No it isn't, unless you write specific code to backup what you consider a stable state, and yet more specific code to restore it and resume execution. Not to mention you would need to re-sync with whatever application at the recieving end of your script. Now if you are writing a standalone application that produces only local results, one does wonder why you would want to use PHP in the first place.

Comment: @kuroineko I'm using php because it's simple to reuse many libraries. However I'd be happy to know other alternates to php, that has mysql & mongoldb drivers and can support my case.

Comment: What you wish for does not depend on the language you're using. You simply can't magically backup the state of a process every second, and even if you did you could not restart it, because a process execution depends of the global system state (interrupts, I/Os, etc). You can at best take a snapshot of a VM, but that's a terribly slow process that would take far more than one second. Either your program is designed to handle this hot restart on its own, or you have to pray that no crash or power failure occurs before it completes. OTOH, computers are not supposed to crash every 10 seconds.

Comment: @kuroineko Wish there's some way, because creating the restart function for a big program is a tough job.

Comment: That's why it's better to think before writing a big program. Welcome to the computer world...

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by saving the state into a file or a table in the db and retrieve the last progress every time i start my script.

Comment: Yes, I do that usually. But I've many local variables and protected variables that I can not store on db. Plus with DB state, there are some problems like you need to use mutiple execution or lock the table